# Datepicker on Android-studio looks different in two different apps I am coding?

Tags: android, xml, datepicker, themes, android-studio

I'm coding two different apps on Android-studio (one I built from the ground up, another that has been worked on for a while). I've added the datepicker xml to both apps:

```
    <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addTurtleDialogButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

but one of them looks like this:

[image: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/Android-SDK_Date-Picker-Dialog/fig1.png]

and the other looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzmcI.png]

I'd really like for the other app to have the better, updated looking datepicker and I've been fiddling with the styles and themes, but I haven't been able to change what the first datepicker looks like. Help!

Comment: Um, those seem to be the same image.

Comment: A different look can be given by different OS versions.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the links!

Comment: @DerGolem how do I check if they are the same OS versions?

Comment: It really looks like a 2.2 version and a 4.x version... So, I wouldn't change that - your users are already used to see their DatePickers in a determinate fashion. Just to answer on how to pick the API level of a particular device: use this integer; `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Comment: @DerGolem I'm running both apps on the same phone though. Wouldn't the datepickers look the same on the same phone?

Comment: On the same phone? So, the apps might use different themes. Android Student M is on the right path.

Comment: The more updated one uses "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and I've changed all the styles of the other app to match that, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date picker pop up are affected by the aap them which you mentioned at your manifest file
change the app them in manifest file you will get the different look.
Hope this will help You!

you can change the as below

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
```

and to know different them you can use this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: could you reiterate what you said? I'm still a bit confused! What do I do in the Manifest file?

Comment: change the aap them.. as mentioned above it's parent="android:.Theme.Holo.Light" you can change i.t to as you want

Comment: Should I do that in the manifest file or the styles.xml? It seems like it's something that should go into styles.xml. If not, where exactly in the manifest should it go? Thanks!

Comment: See what happens in android. You probably have another styles.xml file, perhaps under a directory like "values-v11", that is defining the @style/AppTheme differently than @android:style/Theme.Black and taking precedence over the file you're viewing/modifying.

Comment: if you dont know how to declare them in manifest see this                <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >                 at last where Them.Dialog is there you can put you cursor after Them. and press Ctrl+spacebar you will get the list of aap them...

Comment: I tried changing all the styles to Theme.Holo.Light but it didn't work

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change the specific activity's style in the Manfest file. thanks!

Comment: oh god some time it happens... be through while typing or copying each line in android at least for six month you will become the android master.